# How to declare values in a 2 dimensional struc in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am attempting to create a two dimensional array of strucs, albeit not in the most pretiest of ways, and am running into some syntax errors.  My code is as follows:

```
struct Page
{
  char Column[4];
  int variable;
};
```

.
.
.

```
int main()
{
 struct Page Test[2][2];
 Test[0][0].Column = "ABC";
 Test[0][0].variable = 124;
 Test[0][1].Column = "DEF";
 Test[0][1].variable = 368;
 Test[1][0].Column = "GHI";
 Test[1][1].variable = 763;
}
```

When compiling I get this error:
syntax error before '.' token  <-- this is for every declaration of Test[x][x].whatever.

What exactly did I declare incorrecly?

Comment: `struct Page Test[1][2] = { { {"ABC", 124}, {"DEF", 368} } };`

Comment: `struct Page{ ... };` : `;` add last.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks, I have the ';' in actual code, just accidently left it out here :D

Comment: or `Test[0][0].Column = "ABC";` --> `strcpy(Test[0][0].Column, "ABC");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It seems I made a mistake in my question, let me edit it correctly as I basically defined a 1-D array. . .

Comment: It is not possible to assign the string into an array of `char`. Use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operator cannot be used with arrays in C.

You could use initialization instead (which is not assignment despite using the `=` symbol):

```
struct Page Test[2][2] = {
    { "ABC", 124 }, { "DEF", 368 }, { "GHI", 763 }
};
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, just for my sanity, how does the compiler determine the order to store things in a 2D array? I assume it starts with 0,0 but does it increment rows first or columns?

Comment: fills the first row,etc